# EXECUTE syntax error in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, triggers

i want to execute the following query using execute, it works perfect with select but when i call it in trigger i get this error "ERROR: query has no destination for result data ". I 've tried perform but it doesn't work. The function in select insert rows in a table.

```
select insert_new_grade('title0', return3_6(0), return3_6(1), return3_6(2), s.code)
FROM "student" as s
where find_st(s.grade)>=5;
```

So i've thought of EXECUTE but i get syntax errors . Here is my try :

```
execute 'insert_new_grade('title0', return3_6(0), return3_6(1), return3_6(2), s.code)
FROM "student" as s
where find_st(s.grade)>=5';
```

Can someone tell me what im doing wrong ? Or is there any other idea to make the query work in the trigger function? Thanks in advance..

Here is the trigger :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_d() 
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$ 
BEGIN
    select insert_new_grade('title0', return3_6(0), return3_6(1), return3_6(2), s.code)
    FROM "student" as s
    where find_st(s.grade)>=5;

    return new;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

and here is the insert function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_new_diploma(title0 character(100), prof0 character(11), prof1 character(11)) 
RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO "d_table"(thes0, title, grade, prof, secProf) 
    VALUES (null, title0, null, prof0, prof1);
END
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Comment: in function user `perform` instead of `select`

Comment: @VaoTsun it does not work with perform. I don't get errors but the insert is not being done.

Comment: [edit] your question, and show us your complete function.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ok I've edited it ..

Comment: Your trigger calls `insert_new_grade` for **every** row returned by that query. Is that really what you are trying to achieve? But anyhow, as you are discarding the result of that select you have to use `perform` instead of `select` in the trigger function.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yeah i want insert_new_grade for every row . When i use perform its does not have any result .

Comment: what is the definition of `return3_6` function?.. why do you need `insert_new_diploma` fn at all?.. It just inserts arguments

Answer (score 0):

[41.5.2. Executing a Command With No Result](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html)

> Sometimes it is useful to evaluate an expression or SELECT query but
> discard the result, for example **when calling a function** that has
> side-effects but no useful result value. To do this in PL/pgSQL, use
> the PERFORM statement

emphasis mine.

inside function change `select` to `perform`